# Adding a multiple Select2 selected item with Knockout after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-select2

**EDIT:**
Changing the line click method to:

```
this.addAL = function() {            
  this.selectedState.push("Alabama(AL)")
}
```

Does updates the observable, but the Select2 box still does not shows the tag. I updated the codepen accordingly.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

So I have the following setup:

- A multiple select item managed with Select2
- Knockout v. 3.4
- Select2 v. 4.0.2
- JQuery v. 2.2.2
- A reference to the Knockout integration script (kindly provided by the Select2 dev team here: https://github.com/select2/select2/wiki/Knockout.js-Integration)

The actual Select2 box works OK, but if I try to mark one of the options from the select as selected after the click of a button, it does not work. This is my code so far:

**HTML:**

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-bind="selectedOptions: selectedState, select2: { data: states, placeholder: 'Select a State', tags: true, allowClear: true, formatResult: format }" class="select2" style="width: 200px"></select>
    Selected: <span data-bind="text: selectedState"></span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button data-bind='click:addAL'>Add Alabama</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function(el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(el, function() {
        $(el).select2('destroy');
      });

      var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
          select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.select2);

      $(el).select2(select2);
    },
    update: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        if ("value" in allBindings) {
            if ((allBindings.select2.multiple || el.multiple) && allBindings.value().constructor != Array) {                
                $(el).val(allBindings.value().split(',')).trigger('change');
            }
            else {
                $(el).val(allBindings.value()).trigger('change');
            }
        } else if ("selectedOptions" in allBindings) {
            var converted = [];
            var textAccessor = function(value) { return value; };
            if ("optionsText" in allBindings) {
                textAccessor = function(value) {
                    var valueAccessor = function (item) { return item; }
                    if ("optionsValue" in allBindings) {
                        valueAccessor = function (item) { return item[allBindings.optionsValue]; }
                    }
                    var items = $.grep(allBindings.options(), function (e) { return valueAccessor(e) == value});
                    if (items.length == 0 || items.length > 1) {
                        return "UNKNOWN";
                    }
                    return items[0][allBindings.optionsText];
                }
            }
            $.each(allBindings.selectedOptions(), function (key, value) {
                converted.push({id: value, text: textAccessor(value)});
            });
            $(el).select2("data", converted);
        }
    }
};

function format(state) {
    var originalOption = state.element;
    return state.text.toUpperCase();
}

function State(id, text, children, disabled) {
  this.id = id;
  this.text = text;
  this.disabled = disabled || false;
  this.children = children;
}
function City(id,text,children,disabled) {
  this.id = id;
  this.text = text;
  this.disabled = disabled || false;
  this.children = children;
}

State.prototype.toString = City.prototype.toString =function() {
  return this.text + "(" + this.id + ")";
};

var ViewModel = function () {

    this.states = [
      new State("AL", "Alabama",[],true),
      new State("AK", "Alaska", [ new City("JU", "Juneau")]),
      new State("AZ", "Arizona"),
      /* ... */
      new State("WV", "West Virginia"),
      new State("WI", "Wisconsin"),
      new State("WY", "Wyoming")
    ];

     this.selectedState = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.addAL = function() {            
      this.selectedState().push(new State("AL", "Alabama"))
    }

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Here is a Codepen with the current code I have:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONBVYz

Any lead/hint/advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When pushing to an `observableArray`, you need to push to the `observableArray` instance, not to the `Array` it contains. I.e.: `this.selectedState.push(/* ... */);` in your `addAL` method. The remaining problems mostly have to do with the select box not correctly updating after `selectedState` updates...

Comment: Thank you for your input, I tried and you are right, changing to this.selectedState.push('Alabama(AL)') does get the observable array value updated, but the box does not shows the tag selected. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to trigger a change to let the `select2` widget know you've updated its data (with the `converted` array). Try changing this at the end of your binding's `update` method: `$(el).select2("data", converted").trigger("change");`